# I do not succeed in python to print the movie titles from this XML file

Tags: python, xml, printf, elementtree

I am trying to get python print all the movie names in the XML file but i can't figure it out. I am pretty new to Python can somebody put me in the right direction? i've got it working with an other xml but not with this xml file.

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    for movies in elem.find('decade'):
        print(movies.get('title'))
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><filmsoptv datum="17-10-2018"><film><ft_link>https://www.filmtotaal.nl/film/5704</ft_link><titel>Gekij&amp;ocirc;-ban poketto monsut&amp;acirc; - My&amp;ucirc;ts&amp;ucirc; no gyakush&amp;ucirc;</titel><jaar>1998</jaar><regisseur>Kunihiko Yuyama:Michael Haigney</regisseur><cast>Veronica Taylor:Philip Bartlett:Rachael Lillis:Eric Stuart:Madeleine Blaustein:Ikue Ootani</cast><genre>Animatie:Actie:Avontuur:Familiefilm:Fantasy:Sci-Fi:Sport</genre><land>Japan</land><cover>https://www.filmtotaal.nl/images/covers/jf9qso31vo.jpg</cover><tagline>Witness the rarest pok&amp;Atilde;&amp;Acirc;&amp;copy;mon of all in their first movie!</tagline><duur>96</duur><synopsis>Ash, Pikachu en hun vrienden komen tegenover de machtige Mewtwo te staan.</synopsis><ft_rating>4.9</ft_rating><ft_votes>7</ft_votes><imdb_id>0190641</imdb_id><imdb_rating>6</imdb_rating><imdb_votes>32090</imdb_votes><starttijd>1539765780</starttijd><eindtijd>1539771120</eindtijd><zender>RTL7</zender><filmtip>1</filmtip></film><film><ft_link>https://www.filmtotaal.nl/film/18912</ft_link><titel>Foeksia de miniheks</titel><jaar>2010</jaar><regisseur>Johan Nijenhuis</regisseur><cast>Rachelle Verdel:Porgy Franssen:Annet Malherbe:Marcel Hensema:Lorenso van Sligtenhorst:Kara Borus</cast><genre>Familiefilm</genre><land>Nederland</land><cover>https://www.filmtotaal.nl/images/covers/l0doh3ptzc.jpg</cover><tagline></tagline><duur>95</duur><synopsis>Foeksia is een miniheksje.</synopsis><ft_rating>5.3</ft_rating><ft_votes>6</ft_votes><imdb_id>1382720</imdb_id><imdb_rating>5.6</imdb_rating><imdb_votes>194</imdb_votes><starttijd>1539770400</starttijd><eindtijd>1539775500</eindtijd><zender>NPO3</zender><filmtip>1</filmtip></film>
```

Comment: the word "film" is dutch for movie

Comment: The xml file must start and end with the same entity. In your case, it starts with the tag "filmsoptv" and ends with "film". Give a look here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fix your xml, like andmart noted in the comments. (The tag `fimsoptv` need to be closed)

Each `elem` in your loop refers to one of you movies (or `<film>` tag) of which you can access the title like this:

```
for elem in root:
    titel = elem.find('titel').text
    print(titel)
```

Comment: And also, the code provided looks for a field called 'decade', which doesn't exists on the provided XML. Don't know if thats a typo though